# How can we pass a variable from script inside php and set it to new a variable?(Closed)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

How can we pass a variable from script inside php and set it to new a variable? I want to calculate the user location and the destination location by their coordinates but first I want to get the user coordinates which is already given in the script.

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
  if (($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lon1 == $lon2)) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
      return $miles;
    }
  }
}

$mResult = distance($lat, $long, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
$kmResult = distance($lat, $long, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
$nmResult = distance($lat, $long, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";

echo $kmResult;

?>
<script>

window.onload = function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(bindPosition);
  } else { 
    y.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function bindPosition(position) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/getlocation",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
      lat: position.coords.latitude, 
      long: position.coords.longitude
    },
    success: function(response){
          if(data == "success")
        alert(response); 
    },
    error: function(response){
        alert('Error'+response);
        console.log('Error'+response);
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

the route

```
Route::get('getlocation', 'HomeController@getAllLocations');
```

> ajax response
> [image]

[image]

Comment: Submit a form or use ajax.

Comment: Hi I updated my code above. Need your help.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I also added ajax to push the data in the route but I can't receive alert message that the route receive the data from script

Comment: Is the route handled by the same php code as the one that you've mentioned above? Or rather how is "/getlocation" handled?

Comment: Yes it is route to the php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better for you to separate the View and the API routes called via AJAX. After separating the functions, you need to access the `POST` data using $request->input('lat') and then perform the operations there and return a JSON response.

Also, this code has other issues such as, `$userCoordinates` is not defined...

Comment: what is the code in `HomeController@getAllLocations`? Edit the question with the following data as requested...

Comment: its probably in my ajax because its not throwing the alert

Comment: nothing its just return view('location/all_location');

Comment: or probably the `/getlocation` route for improper handling of data. What you can try is add an error block, so that if there is an error you'll be notified. and we can then debug the problem...

Comment: and is this view `view('location/all_location')` the same as the code that you mentioned in the question?

Comment: I believe you are using laravel (are you?). I think that the problem is that the post data is not passed on to the view. You can try adding an error handler to be notified of any error in your ajax request...

Comment: Make this change to `HomeController@getAllLocations`: 

`getAllLocations($req){
 return view('location/all_location')->with($req->post())
}`

And inside the view, revert the changes that I mentioned in the answer. That is, make it as before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223856/discussion-between-frustrated-dev-and-illusion).